# Extracting json from html

Tags: python

I have html files with blocks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript> 
var json1 = {
// ...
} 
</script>
```

Using the names of the vars - e.g. "json1" - what is a straightforward way to extract the json? Could a regex do it, or do I need something like Beautiful Soup?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

yes you need both regex and beautiful soup

```
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

html = //Your html output
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('json1'))
json_text = re.search(r'^\s*json1\s*=\s*({.*?})\s*;\s*$', 
                        script.string, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE).group(1)
data = json.loads(json_text)
print(data['json1'])
```

Comment: Nice answer.  In bs4 4.4+, the arg is [`string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) instead of `text`

Comment: Wow, thanks. I could not have come up with that regex easily.

Comment: This works only if there isn't a nested `{ ... }` object in the JSON data structure.

Comment: There are a lot of nested {...} so this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I found something simple that worked in my case. Get the position of the "var json1 = ", then call html.find("", startOfJson1). Use the indexes to slice the json from the string.